# Append the output results to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a web scraping company logos with clearbit API. Like below(see code)

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {'name':  ['tcs', 'orange', 'linkedin'],
        'domain': ["tcs.com",
                    "orange.com",
                    "linkedin.com"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")

for i in df['domain']:
    driver.get("https://logo.clearbit.com/" + str(i))
    clear_api_html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    clear_logo_access = clear_api_html.find_all('img')
    output_dict = {'Logo': clear_logo_access, 'Website': i}
    print(output_dict)
```

And I am having the output like below

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
{'Logo': [<img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/tcs.com" style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;"/>], 'Website': 'tcs.com'}
{'Logo': [<img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/orange.com" style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;"/>], 'Website': 'orange.com'}
{'Logo': [<img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/linkedin.com" style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;"/>], 'Website': 'linkedin.com'}
```

In the dictionery format, however I wanted the output results to append it to the existing dataframe.

expected output:

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over all domains. So if you append all urls to a list during the iteration, you can simply add a key to the dictionary.

```
url_list = []
for i in df['domain']:
    driver.get("https://logo.clearbit.com/" + str(i))
    clear_api_html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    clear_logo_access = clear_api_html.find_all('img')
    clear_url = clear_logo_access[0]['src']
    url_list.append(clear_url)
data['clearbit_url'] = logo_list
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, still my logo column has ```[<img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/tcs.com" style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;"/>]``` I just need the src url like ```https://logo.clearbit.com/tcs.com``` I used strip function but it doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the answer, no it extracts the url from the beautiful soup result set. Note that the code assumes only one images is found per website now. If you want to find all images you should do a for loop over clear_logo_access and get the url for all elements in the resultset.